# how to look for sentences inside a dataframe which contain single characters in any place

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to printout sentences from a dataframe that contains words with one character  no matter where it is beginning of the sentence middle or end of it the code im trying is

```
lookfor = '[' + re.escape("A-Za-z") + ']'

tdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, nrows=0).columns[0]
skip = int(tdata.count(' ') == 0)
tdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip)



filtered = tdata[tdata.sentences.str.contains(lookfor, regex=True, na=False)]
print(filtered)

#a sample set
-----------------------------

#hi, how are; you z
#im  w good thanks
#How  am I
#good, what about  you
#my name is alex
#K hello, alex how are you !
#it  is a car
#great news
#thanks!
-----------------------------

expected output 

-----------------------------
#hi, how are; you z
#im  w good thanks
#How  am I
#K hello, alex how are you !
#it  is a car
-----------------------------
```

and it does not work even if I wrote all the letter inside the lookfor array it will print any sentence containing those letter not when they come alone any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with one words with word boundaries and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['sentences'].str.contains(r'\b\w{1}\b')]
print (df)
                     sentences
0           hi, how are; you z
1            im  w good thanks
2                    How  am I
5  K hello, alex how are you !
6                 it  is a car
```

EDIT: For exclude `A` and `I` you can use `replace` before compare:

```
df = df[df['sentences'].str.replace(r'\b[AI]\b', '').str.contains(r'\b\w{1}\b')]
print (df)
                     sentences
0           hi, how are; you z
1            im  w good thanks
5  K hello, alex how are you !
6                 it  is a car
```

Or:

```
df = df[~df['sentences'].str.contains(r'\b[AI]\b') & 
         df['sentences'].str.contains(r'\b\w{1}\b')]
print (df)
                     sentences
0           hi, how are; you z
1            im  w good thanks
5  K hello, alex how are you !
6                 it  is a car
```

Comment: can I do something to exclude letters like A and I ?

Comment: @programmingfreak - One idea is replace them to empty strings before compare, answer was edited.

Comment: the answer works perfectly for English script, do you have any idea how to implement it on arabic script as well like whenever single characters come in Arabic like **ب** **ذ**

Comment: @programmingfreak - hmmm, I think the best is create special question for arabic match, never working with arabic, so not idea

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df.loc[df.sentences.str.contains(r"([^\w]|^)\w([^\w]|$)")]
```

Outputs:

```py
                     sentences
0           hi, how are; you z
1            im  w good thanks
2                    How  am I
5  K hello, alex how are you !
6                 it  is a car
```

Comment: can I do something to exclude letters like A and I ?

Comment: That would be something like: ```r"([^\w]|^)[bcdefghj...BCDEFGHJ...]([^\w]|$)"``` Just put inside the letters you wish to keep